# C++ LPTSTR problem calling CreateProcessAsUser with getenv

Tags: c++, createprocessasuser, getenv, lptstr

I am trying to call function CreateProcessAsUser.  Passing constant string is fine.  Trying to pick up an Environment variable using char* getenv(const char name) is causing me a problem.

If I use the following, notepad.exe will run.

```
CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDup, _T("c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"), 
                    _T("c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"), NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                    dwCreationFlag, pEnvironment, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

However, if I use the following nothing runs.

```
CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDup, _T("MyAppName"), 
                    (LPTSTR)getenv("MYENVVAR"), NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                    dwCreationFlag, pEnvironment, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Have I specified the getenv and (LPTSTR) correctly?

I have tried using user and system environment vars containing c:\\windows\\notepad.exe and c:\windows\notepad.exe.

Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the cast to `(LPTSTR)`—if the compiler is giving you an error message there without the cast, then inserting a cast to shut the compiler up is **the wrong thing to do**.  The compiler is trying to tell you something.  In that case, you're compiling a Unicode application, and you're trying to pass an ANSI string when a Unicode string is expected—use [`_tgetenv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx) instead of `getenv`.

Comment: Do you know if `getenv` succeeded?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: ["Since the compiler was unable to convert the parameter, let's give it some help and stick a cast in front. There, that shut up the compiler. Those compiler guys are so stupid."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx)

Comment: Use _wgetenv() to solve your problem, underscore-t is archaic.  The best thing to do is to set the 2nd argument to NULL and the 3rd argument to exepath + " " + arguments.  That makes sure that some C programs that rely on argv[0] being the program path don't fall over.  CreateProcess is rocket science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter, `lpCommandLine` is `LPTSTR` which means it must be writeable memory.  You need to copy the command line into a writeable string before calling `CreateProcessAsUser`.

The documentation for `getenv` states:

> It is not safe to modify the value of the environment variable using the returned pointer.

You therefore cannot pass this as the `lpCommandLine` parameter of `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Your first call to `CreateProcessAsUser` appears to be wrong too since you also are not passing writeable memory for `lpCommandLine`.

Of course it's most likely that your immediate problem is that you are mixing ANSI and Unicode.  If your app is Unicode then you need to call `_wgetenv`, or `_tgetenv` if you really do want to target both ANSI and Unicode from the same source.  But make sure you copy it into a writeable buffer before passing it on.

Finally, as Adam commented, every time you write a cast, there is a strong possibility that you are making a mistake.

Comment: Ah, good call, I forgot that the `*getenv` functions return read-only but non-`const` pointers.  As for why `CreateProcessAsUser` and `CreateProcess` require writable command lines, see [Why does the CreateProcess function modify its input command line?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/01/9673254.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

getenv() will always return a char* no matter what character set your application is set to use.  Try using _tgetenv() instead, as it adjusts between char* and wchar_t* as needed.